# How to move issue within GitHub organization?

Tags: git, github

With [GitHub organization](https://github.com/blog/674-introducing-organizations) I can see [all issues in one place](https://github.com/blog/959-issues-dashboard-for-organizations)

URL example `https://github.com/organizations/Nodeclipse/dashboard/issues`

**How to move issue within GitHub organization?**

Related:
General approach: [GitHub-2-GitHub issues import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356451/github-2-github-issues-import)
[How do I move an issue on github to another repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720718/how-do-i-move-an-issue-on-github-to-another-repo)

Comment: what exactly is your question? You want to move an issue from repo to another?

Comment: For reference, [discussion on Github](https://github.com/holman/feedback/issues/413)

Comment: Commenting, so as to link the questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720718/how-do-i-move-an-issue-on-github-to-another-repo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there is no *official* way to do it.

but, there are some scripts that will read in issues and recreate them in another repo, like this one: https://github.com/collective/collective.developermanual/blob/master/gh-issues-import.py

but in our org, we just close the issue (with a moved message) and manually recreate it.

Comment: I created a python script (based on the gh-issues-import) that exactly handles this task automatically: https://github.com/jotweh/IssueRelocate

Answer (score 2):

I've created a Chrome Extension called Kamino that will clone issues from one repository to another. It will also close the original issue. It will also eventually be available for MS Edge. Granted, this will only move one issue at a time but should be useful to you.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kamino/ffdebockfdjileaojbbccofhgncmioaf?hl=en-US

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move all issues from one org into another (which is exactly my use case) then GitHub transfer is a good option

See this Issue for the how to https://github.com/fluentsharp/FluentSharp/issues/80